# Viewing GDAL (and other) raw commands in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal

It was once the case in early versions of QGIS that you could fire up the GDAL extensions and view the underpinning commands being driven by GUI work, which could then be used independently from a console outside QGIS using GDAL. But I can't seem to find where this console output is hidden in 3.16.x. Has this been removed from the application? Ideally, I'd like to extract the precise GDAL commands being driven by a few analysis tools which are getting bogged down on my laptop and run then on a high performance cluster.

Comment: You may need to be more specific. Running 3.24.1, the GUI wrapper for GDAL Warp (Raster -> Projections -> Warp), for example, does still have a "GDAL/OGR console call" display near the bottom of the panel that shows the command line.

Comment: Ah right. I'm working with vector operations (specifically qgis:difference) on shapefiles. This is in MacOS (11.6) with QGIS LTR 3.16.15. But am happy to upgrade if this is addressed in a newer version!

Comment: The newer version of QGIS does not seem to provide a view of the command arguments for the Difference command. But I don't think that is a wrapper for a GDAL command either. In the QGIS options (Processing tab, Menus list), Difference is listed among the QGIS native c++ functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a GDAL tool, just look at the bottom of the tool dialog to view/copy the "GDAL/OGR console call" command string.

However, `qgis:difference` is a native QGIS tool, not a GDAL tool. You can see which is which easily as QGIS tool providers have a QGIS logo and GDAL tools have a GDAL logo in the processing toolbox.

[image]